# How set up Angular2 Template Driven form element with two-way binding as well as template driven form validation

Tags: html, angular

How do I correctly set up an Angular template driven form element to have both template driven validation as well as two-way binding? Is it possible?

I have tried a couple different ways of using ngModel, but cannot seem to get two-way binding to work, without some drawback. I am sure I am missing something stupid.

When I use `[(ngModel)]="city"` as well as well as `#city="ngModel"` as per example below, I get the following error:

> Error: Cannot assign value "$event" to template variable "city".
> Template variables are read-only.

**Element setup:**

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3 mr-3">
  <label
    [class.error-label]="!city1.valid && city1.touched"
    for="city"
    >City or Town*
  </label>
  <input
    type="text"
    id="city"
    ngModel
    name="city"
    required
    #city="ngModel"
    [(ngModel)]="city"
  />
  <span *ngIf="!city.valid && city.touched" class="error-text"
    >Please enter your City or Town</span
  >
</div>
```

When I do not use `[(ngModel)]="city"`, I am not getting two-way binding. And when I rename my local reference `#city="ngModel"` to something like `#cityWhatever="ngModel"`, the value for `city` is `undefined` when submitting the form:

```
<form
 (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(personalDetails)"
 #personalDetails="ngForm"
>
```

I am running Angular version: "@angular/common": "~9.1.11"

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please use one of the following.
 #city="ngModel" or 
    [(ngModel)]="city"

Comment: Then I don't get access to the local reference #city

Comment: remove #cityWhatever="ngModel"

Comment: That is not the correct approach. I need a local reference for validation and access to the value of the input when submitting the form.

Comment: Remove the ngModel

Comment: That does not fix the local reference error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this and remove ngModel

```
<input
 type="text"
 id="city"
 name="city"
 required
 #city="ngModel"
 [(ngModel)]="model.city"
/>
<span *ngIf="!city.valid && city.touched" class="error-text">
  Please enter your City or Town
</span>
```

Comment: Do I then simply add the model to my Component with the various properties?